# Unable to Populate ParentId and RecordtypeId in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have created a custom record creation page using LWC and overridden the standard new button with the help of Aura component. But I am having an issue in populating the ParentId and Recordtype Id in the record. Can someone please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to [edit] and share you component code? Have you tried anything in particular?

Answer (score 1):

onload (action) => The action triggered when the form data is loaded.

Use onload method

```
handleOnLoad(event) {
    var record = event.detail.records;
    var fields = record[this.recordId].fields; // record['0010K000026Y******'].fields;
    const accName = fields.Name.value;      
    alert(accName);
    //const myfieldVal = fields.myfield__c.value;
    //alert(myfieldVal);
}
```

With the help of this you can populate any value in record form.

Comment: Hi Karan, I tried using onLoad method but its still not working. But I came up with an alternate solution and created a custom button of type url, and fetching the parentid from url. This is working fine but it overriding the record type selection page. Any solution for this?